# Coding the service layer with promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I want to take out my CRUD Logic out of the routes and put it in a service layer.

So basically I want to call the service layer like that:

```
const service = require("../service/post")

router.post("/new", (req, res) => {
    service.createPost(req.body.titel, req.body.description, req.body.tags, function(id){
        console.log("Created post with id: " + id)
        res.redirect("index")
    })
})
```

In my `postService.js` file I have the following function:

```
function createPost(titel, description, tags, callback) {

    const post = {
        titel: titel,
        description: description,
        tags: tags,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        deleted: false,
    }
    console.log("Create Post: " + post.titel + " " + post.description + " " + post.tags + " " + post.createdAt + " " + post.deleted)

    knex("posts").insert(post, "id").then(id => {
        console.log(id)
        callback(id[0])
    })
}
```

Currently I am using a `callback` to handle this function.

Any suggestion how to use a more promise based style to return back the id, and the code in the router waits when the promise is finished?

Thank you for your replies!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, you can get rid of your `callback` parameter and return the promise returned by `knex`

```
createPost(...) {
  ...
  return knex('posts').insert(post, "id");
}
```

Then in your route you can `await` the result

```
router.post('/new', async (req, res) => {
  const id = await service.createPost(...);
  console.log("Created post with id: " + id[0]);
  res.redirect("index");
});
```

Alternatively, if you want to pre-process the response from `knex` (as it returns an array) then you can return a new Promise

```
async createPost(...) {
  ...
  const result = await knex('posts').insert(...);
  return result[0];
}
```

FWIW I'd recommend the latter as it provides a clean separation between the layers.

Comment: One thing I would do extra, is wrap inside a try except,.  Node.JS will currently log an error, but in future may just terminate the App.  Basically all end point promises in node.js really need handling.

Comment: @Keith error handling omitted for brevity, but yes I agree, have the service layer completely encapsulate the storage errors.